# Using array in select dropdown

Tags: php

Getting undefined item when i submit the form using POST method.

```
<?php   
$reason = array(
    "Expected delivery date has changed and the product is arriving at a later date",
    "Product is being delivered to a wrong address(Customer’s mistake)",
    "Product is not required anymore.",
    "Cheaper alternative available for lesser price.",
    "I am not going to be available in town due to some urgent travel.",
    "Change in delivery address, non deliverable pincode."
);
?>
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" required>
     <option>Seclect reason</option>
     <?php
     foreach($reason as $item){
       echo '<option value="' . strtolower($item) .'">' . $item . '</option>';
      }
     ?> 
</select>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="cancel">Submit</button>
```

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1" required> try giving your select box a name attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to set the `name` attribute for your `select` element e.g `reasons` then you'll be able to get the value of item like `$_POST['reasons']`. e.g: **Product is not required anymore.**

**N.B** try to use smaller value to your `option` value e.g use `$reason` as an associative array and set the **key** to option's `value` and **value** to options inner text;

```
<select class="form-control" name="reasons" id="sel1" required>
    <option>Select reason</option>
    <?php
$reason = array("Expected delivery date has changed and the product is arriving at a later date","Product is being delivered to a wrong address(Customer’s mistake)","Product is not required anymore.","Cheaper alternative available for lesser price.","I am not going to be available in town due to some urgent travel.","Change in delivery address, non deliverable pincode.");
foreach($reason as $item){
    echo '<option value="'.strtolower($item).'">'.$item.'</option>';
}
    ?> </select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="cancel">Submit</button>
```